# Can I use auto layout with UIPageViewController's pages?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout, uipageviewcontroller

I have the following controller stack:

```
 - UINavigationController
   - UITableViewController
     - UIPageViewController
       - MyTableViewController1
       - MyTableViewController2
       - MyTableViewController3
```

I am using AutoLayout and respecting the layout guides throughout the whole application.

However, MyTableViewController1|2|3 are instantiated inside the UIPageViewController DataSource methods and not through storyboard segues. I'm loading the viewControllers from storyboard using:

```
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyTableViewController1|2|3"];
```

MyTableViewController1|2|3.adjustScrollViewInsets = YES in storyboard.

But the adjustScrollViewInsets does *nothing*

In MyTableViewController1|2|3.viewDidLayoutSubViews I log the following:

```
self.view.frame = {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}
self.bottomLayoutGuide = <_UILayoutGuide: 0x1701b0bc0; frame = (0 531; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x17022fde0>>
self.topLayoutGuide = <_UILayoutGuide: 0x1781ae700; frame = (0 0; 0 64); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x178220ca0>>
```

It seems I'm just missing some little detail here. Answers I found on stack-overflow are all for autolayout = NO situations.

The problem is MyTableViewController1|2|3's cells render behind the navigationBar.

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry, just updated: The problem is MyTableViewController1|2|3's cells render behind the navigationBar.

Comment: @PedroBorges Hey dude, I'm doing a similar thing did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: Nope, I resigned using UIPageView altogether